# How do you say "to name after"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, In English I would say *he was named after his grandfather* because he has the same name as his grandfather. How would I express that in Esperanto?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Li estis nomita laŭ sia avo

From the tekstaro:

- Jackson Square: publika placo en Nov-Orleano, **nomita laŭ** la usona prezidanto Andrew Jackson
- ...germanoj estus ŝokitaj ekscii, ke la ĉefurbo ne estis **nomita laŭ** la nobla ‘urso’...
- Kirilico1, **nomita laŭ** sia kreinto Cirilo...

Answer (score 4):

- *Li portas/ricevis la nomon de sia avo.*
- *Al li estis donita la nomo de lia avo.*
- *Li estis nomita (baptita) per la nomo de sia avo.*
- *Li estis nomita samnome de sia avo.*
- *Li estis nomita je sia avo.*

The expression *nomita laŭ* is common, but it is not ideal, as the following examples show:

- *Mi estis nomita de mia patrino laŭ [= je] mia avo, laŭ mia patro.* I was named by my mother after my grandfather, according to my father.
- *Ŝia patrino nomis ŝin, laŭ ties avo.* Her mother named her (after/according to) her grandfather.

Comment: In Vikipedio *nomita je* is also used for [*named in his honor*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Esclangon) and for when the naming took place(e.g. [*Ĝi estis nomita je 1850 de termezuristo*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairmount#Historio). So *je* is not perfect either.

Comment: "To name after X" and "to name in X's honor" are basically synonyms, and *nomita je 1850* cannot realistically be considered ambiguous. *Laŭ* is definitely a bad choice.

Comment: When ambiguity might arise, _laŭdire de_ (1200 google hits) is a good replacement for _laŭ_ with the meaning _according to_: _Ŝia patrino nomis ŝin, laŭdire de ties avo_

Answer (score 2):

***laŭ***, i.e. *Li estis nomata laŭ sia avo.*

I don't have a zamenhofian citation as a reference, but if you google `"nomata laŭ"` or `"nomita laŭ"` you will get tons of results.

Answer (score 2):

***Oni nomis lin laŭ lia avo***

You can also say *li estis nomita laŭ sia avo* but if you can avoid the passive, then you should.

- oni nomis la stratojn laŭ la familioj

Comment: It has to be "Oni nomis lin laŭ lia avo". When you make the sentence passive, however, "sia" is thw right choice, as the person it refers to is then the subject.

Comment: I don't agree with your statement that if you can avoid the passive, you should. There are contexts in which the passive is the better choice, and I would say that this is one of them.